# Multiline to associative array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, preg-match, associative-array

I have a block of text in a variable `$s`:

```
FOO:317263
BAR:abcd
BAZ:s fsiu sfd sdf s dfsdddddd
```

**What's the easiest way (and with good parsing performance) to get an associative array:**

```
$a = array('FOO' => '317263', 'BAR' => 'abcd', 'BAZ' => 's fsiu sfd sdf s dfsdddddd');
```

**?**

Up to now, I used:

```
 preg_match("/^FOO:(.*)$/m", $s, $matches1);
 $a['FOO'] = $matches1[1];
 preg_match("/^BAR:(.*)$/m", $s, $matches1);
 $a['BAR'] = $matches1[1];
 ...
```

but is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: I would use `explode()`: 1. explode by newline, then 2. loop through the results and explode by `:` and put it into an associative array.

Comment: What if there are duplicates in terms of array keys? (Because associative arrays could break)

Comment: @nice_dev There are no duplicates in the keys, and if ever it happens I'm ok if something breaks because it should not happen anyway.

Comment: @Basj Ok fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can use a non-regex approach like

```
$s = 'FOO:317263
BAR:abcd
BAZ:s fsiu sfd sdf s dfsdddddd';

$a = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $s) as $line) {
    $chnk = explode(':', $line, 2);
    $a[$chnk[0]] = $chnk[1];
}
print_r($a);
```

After splitting with LF, `explode(':', $line, 2);` is used to split the line with the first occurrence of a colon.

If you can have different/mixed line endings, replace `explode("\n", $s)` with `preg_split('~\R+~', $s)` or even `preg_split('~\R+~u', $s)` if you deal with Unicode.

If you know you need to do some more matching than you revealed in the question, and you really need a regex, you may consider

```
$a = array();
if (preg_match_all('~^(\w+)\h*:\h*(.+)~m', $s, $matches)) {
    $a = array_combine($matches[1],trim($matches[2]));
}
print_r($a);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/8qMSg) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yXPO1U/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` flag)
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\h*:\h*` - a colon enclosed with zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 2: the rest of the line.

You can also use [`parse_ini_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php):

```php
$a = parse_ini_string(preg_replace('/^([^:\v]*):(.*)/m', '$1=\'$2\'', $s), FALSE);
```

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/QhlWC).

The `preg_replace('/^([^:\v]*):(.*)/m', '$1=\'$2\'', $s)` part replaces all first `:` chars on each line with a `=`, wraps the parts after the first `:` with single quotes (to let `parse_ini_string` correctly handle additional `=`s), and `parse_ini_string` gets the array of keys and values.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew ! Out of curiosity, can your first solution be made nearly a one-liner (I am mostly a Python guy, and I usually do those things with a dict comprehension in one line) and `array_filter` or `array_map`?

Comment: @Basj I am not sure if the first solution is that one-lineable, but the `parse_ini_string` coupled with `preg_replace` looks short enough.

Comment: @Basj There are no list/dictionary comprehension equivalents in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If it is guaranteed that the values on the right of ':' do not contain ':' or "\n":

```
$s = <<< STRING
FOO:317263
BAR:abcd
BAZ:s fsiu sfd sdf s dfsdddddd
STRING;

$arr = array_column(array_chunk(preg_split("/[:\n]/", $s), 2), 1, 0);

print_r($arr);
```

This will print:

```
Array
(
    [FOO] => 317263
    [BAR] => abcd
    [BAZ] => s fsiu sfd sdf s dfsdddddd
)
```

Comment: Nice solution! The value on the right of `:` might contain `:` such as `COMMENT:Try this: print(hello)`. In this case can we split with the *first* `:`?

Comment: With you current solution, it takes the first and second part when split with `:`. Can we take first part / all the remaining parts? i.e. split only with the first `:`

Answer (score 0):

Build a stream from your string and read it as a csv:

```
$s = <<<'DATA'
FOO:317263
BAR:abcd
BAZ:s fsiu sfd sdf s df:sdddddd
DATA;

$handle = fopen("data://text/plain,$s",'r');

$result = [];

while (false !== $cols = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ':')) {
    $result[array_shift($cols)] = implode(':', $cols);
}

print_r($result);
```

---

Always using a stream, but more "functional":

```
$result = array_reduce(file("data://text/plain,$s"), function($c,$i) {
    [$k, $v] = explode(':', $i, 2);
    $c[$k] = rtrim($v);
    return $c;
}, $c=[]);

print_r($result);
```